# Routing Issue in Asp.net mvc 5

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

i am working in Asp.net mvc 5. I am having issue with Html.actionlink.

```
@Html.ActionLink(cust.Name, "Details", "Customers", new { id = cust.Id }, 
null);
```

cust.name is the text displayed , Details is the method in Customers Controller and i am passing id as parameter in Details method.
But issue is that i have chechked it through debugging, the control does not goes to Details method on clicking the the link(cust.name).

i have been stuck here, please help

Comment: So what is happening when you click on it ? Do you have some js code which is hijacking the click event and stopping the normal click navigation behavior ?

Comment: What code is generated with this razor block? Use developer tools (F12 on web browser). If link is empty this is problem with routing.

Comment: It displays a 404 error :
The resource you are looking for has been changed or removed 
Customers/Details

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`@Html.ActionLink()` in first parameter is string, so you can not use model property. Instead of using `@Html.ActionLink()` we can use `<a/>` tag.

```
<a href="@Url.Action("Details","Customers",new{ id = cust.Id})">@cust.Name</a>
```

Comment: Of course you can use a model property! This is nonsense. If OP's `ActionLink()` did not work then neither will this